# Lambda passed to template not defined

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

I was playing with C++17's class template argument deduction today. The first obvious idea that came to mind was passing a callable as template parameter. A callable, that's among other things a lambda, why not. Let's try that.

```
template<typename F> class foo
{
F f;
public:
    foo(F in) : f(in) { f(); /* not very useful, admitted */ }
};

void bar() { puts("a"); }

int main()
{
    auto a = foo(bar);
    auto b = foo([](){ puts("b"); });

    return (void) a, (void) b, 0;
}
```

Here is what clang (5.0, r300688) has to say about it:

> warning: function '<(lambda at [source
>   location])>' has internal linkage but is not defined

The code compiles and certainly "works fine" but the warning suggests the compiler is not altogether happy with it.

I'm ready to agree that the lambda has internal linkage (being anonymous it's not accessible elsewhere in the same translation unit, so sure enough it's inaccessible in another one), but what about it. I *don't want to* access it from another translation unit.
The part about lacking definition strikes me as funny, I wouldn't even know how to write a lambda without defining it.

In summary: What gives? What to make of that? I don't like warnings, not only do they make the build less pretty, but they *usually* mean something is wrong and undefined behavior of sorts may bite you soon. On the other hand, how can I make a lambda *more defined* than it already is by writing out its definition?

Comment: g++7 is completely fine with your code. Here's a [smaller reproducible example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/enjBdYurTAX2GRr6)

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=20296

Comment: `return (void) a, (void) b, 0;`  why?

Comment: First, the lambda doesn't have internal linkage; it has no linkage whatsoever as a local class. Second, the warning is about the deduction guide implicitly synthesized by the compiler, not the lambda. Third, the warning is complete nonsense: deduction guides can't be defined, only declared.

Comment: @Brandon: `return (void) a, (void) b, 0;` does nothing, twice (but uses the otherwise unused objects so they are not optimized out, nor generate warnings) and returns zero.

Comment: @Brandon This would be equivalent to ```[[maybe_unused]]``` declarations.

Comment: @Damon `foo` has a non trivial constructor and cannot be optimized out.

Comment: @BenjaminT Sure, but it can still generate unused local variable warnings, which would confuse matters since the question is about an unrelated warning.

Comment: @DanielH A proper C++ compiler shouldn't generate warnings or errors for unused local variables with either a non trivial constructor or destructor. You can see the answer to this question (it also has a link to a comparison of compiler warnings): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646068/how-to-make-visual-studio-2010-warn-about-unused-variables You can also find g++ bug reports and fixes to remove such warnings (e.g https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10416)

Comment: @BenjaminT A C++ compiler can warn about whatever it wants; there is no point where the C++ standard says a diagnostic is *disallowed*. Neither G++ nor Clang warn about this one even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (and with Clang, not even `-Weverything` does it), but in the question you linked about `std::string` I *would* want a warning (as did the original asker), and I wouldn’t be surprised if they added it back in at least some cases (although probably still not enabled by `-Wall -Wextra`). In any case, it’s a clear idiom that doesn’t do any harm whether or not there are warnings.

Comment: @DanielH Sure the standard does not disallow it, but doing so would generate useless warnings for codes using RAII classes. That's why all current major C++ compilers do not generate such warnings. If you want to enable such warnings, using g++, you have to do it on each relevant class using the `warn_unused` attribute.

Comment: @BenjaminT I was actually surprised by my Clang results. It does memory allocation/deallocation elision; I expected that it would notice that it had *optimized out* all the side effects of my `std::string s = "Hello, world!";` and it really was unused with no side effects. That doesn’t apply in this case because output can’t be optimized out at compile time, but it does indicate that these warnings could be turned up (or at least *included as an option that’s disabled by default*) without causing any problems. And the `(void) a` part is still clear and harmless even if it’s unnecessary.

Comment: So it was a bug, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this is a compiler glitch. Using Clang compiler of Visual Studio 2017 only this error is generated "cannot refer to class template 'foo' without a template argument list" for a and b instantiation in main function. If the function type is specified as template parameter, there are no warnings and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into a few nonsense warnings that looked, and smelled, similar to yours. I tried a bunch of hand-wavey fixes with the idea that I could force the linker’s hand (if you will) – but at the end of the day I realized that I was trying to compile C++14 code with a `-std=c++17` flag. You may want to double-check your own standards flags (and possibly your corresponding `-stdlib=…` flags as well).