# How to make Visual Studio 2010 warn about unused variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, stdstring

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; // no warning
    int i;    // warning C4101

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why does Visual Studio warn me about the unused variable `i` but not about `s` in the example?
2. I assume that the compiler is not sure about side effects of the string constructor. Is this the reason for not showing a warning?
3. Can I somehow enable warnings about unused string variables?

My warning level is set to 4.

Comment: Aren't std::strings initialized as empty strings while "true values" - char, int, double, float, etc- are garbage values since they are uninitialized? As far as warning are concerned i am not sure, I use resharper which is a plugin for VS that does that for me.

Comment: I'd have to check the actual implementation, but most string constructors would call `operator new`. That's an observable side effect.

Comment: For what it is worth, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (both 6.3 & 7.1) don't warn about `s` with `g++ -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the constructor for std::string is called. *The string is not used*, end of line. I don't get why there is a discussion. This is something the visual studio compiler is missing....

Comment: @DrumM the compiler is not aware what `std::string` actually is, it only knows that is is a class with a constructor and a destructor. The constructor could potentially do something useful, for example transform the mouse pointer into an hour glass and the destructor would revert the hourglass into an arrow. Other compilers don't show warnings either: See [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/V47glJ)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jabberwocky! Indeed, all compilers are missing it :p Just saying, there is a problem with the C++ specification. As "std::string a;" is an empty string and furthermore defined by the standard, this could have been implemented. Mostly just defining an object with a default constructor without using the object looks nasty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hypothesize that compilers only warn about unused variables for trivially constructible/destructible types.

```
template<typename>
struct Empty
{

};

template<typename T>
struct Trivial : Empty<T>
{
    int* p;
    int i;
};

template<typename>
struct NonTrivial
{
    NonTrivial() {}
};

template<typename>
struct TrivialE
{
    TrivialE& operator=(const TrivialE&) {}
};

struct NonTrivial2
{
    NonTrivial2() {}
};

struct NonTrivialD
{
    ~NonTrivialD() {}
};

int main()
{
    Empty<int> e;      // warning
    Trivial<int> t;    // warning
    NonTrivial<int> n; // OK
    TrivialE<int> te;  // warning
    NonTrivial2 n2;    // OK
    NonTrivialD nd;    // OK
}
```

[Comparison of compilers' treatment](https://godbolt.org/g/TYunXF)

As can be observed, they are consistent.

Since `std::string` cannot possibly be trivially destructible, the compilers won't warn about it.

So to answer your question: you can't.

Comment: This is a nice template trick, but to implement this for every type that's overkill... Even the QObject doesn't have such a construct I believe, but this could be the place (if it wasn't generating to much code).

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to declare a constructor (and a destructor) `pure` because it's all state and side effects ... even though in effect the initialized object is a constructor's "output". Otherwise the compiler should only issue a warning if the constructor and destructor are pure (and may have no side effects other than initializing/unwinding the constructed object which is never used).

Answer (score 2):

There is no warning because actually there is no unused variable `s`. `s` is an instance of the `string` class and this class has a constructor which is called upon the declaration `string s;`, therefore `s` is used by it's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not a primitive type, while `int` is. Non-primitive types have constructors and destructors, which may perform some useful functions: memory management, output to screen and so on, therefore declaration of a non-primitive type does not necessarily mean that the variable is not used. `string` does not do anything like this, of course, but probably they supress warnings for known types also having in mind that you may come up with the idea of redifining the `string` behavior (and you *can* do this by editing some header files since `string` is based on a template class).

Comment: Actually, you can't, IIRC, because VS2010 treats `std::string` specially in the CRT. That's entirely legal on their side, because it's part of implementation.